# Help in question, Inner product space.

Tags: linear-algebra, inner-products

given those vectors **u=<a,b>** and  **v=<c,d>** (above R)

<u,v> defined for real M -> **ac-3ad-3bc+Mbd**.

i need to find all M valuves that <u,v> defines an inner product

ive tried to use the conditions : **<u,v> = <v,u>**

**<u,u> >= 0, and <u,u> = 0 if and only if u = 0**,

**<u+v,w> = <u,w> + <v,w>**

and yet i struggle to find any M.
can anyone help me please to figure this out?

Comment: Welcome to MSE. For some basic information about writing mathematics at this site see, *e.g.*, [basic help on mathjax notation](/help/notation), [mathjax tutorial and quick reference](//math.meta.stackexchange.com/q/5020), [main meta site math tutorial](//meta.stackexchange.com/a/70559) and [equation editing how-to](//math.meta.stackexchange.com/q/1773).

Answer (score 1):

**Hint:** Your function $\langle \cdot, \cdot \rangle$ can be written as
$$
\left\langle \pmatrix{a\\b}, \pmatrix{c\\d} \right\rangle = \pmatrix{a&b}\pmatrix{1&-3\\-3&M} \pmatrix{c\\d}.
$$
For every $M$, this function satisfies all of requirements except possible for the requirement that $\langle u,u \rangle > 0$ for all non-zero $u \in \Bbb R^2$.

For an approach without linear algebra:

> Note that
> $$\langle u,u \rangle = (a-3b)^2 + k b^2$$
>  for some $k$ that depends of $M$.